# What is the best way to store formatted timestamp in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

What is the best way to store a timestamp value in Postgresql in a specific format.
For example I would like to store a `TIMESTAMP '2020-07-09 17:29:30.873513Z'` down to the minute and ignore seconds value.

I can drop the seconds by using `date_trunc('minute', TIMESTAMP '2020-07-09 17:29:30.873513Z')` Is there anyway for me to specify this format in the column itself when I create a table?

Comment: Don't format it when storing (use a proper `timestamp` or `timestamptz` column) - you do the formatting when you **display** the values in your application.

Comment: You can force Postgres to drop the microseconds using `timestamp(0)` but not to ignore the seconds completely.

Answer (score 1):

Don't store formatted timestamps in the database, use `timestamp with time zone` or `timestamp without time zone`. You would lose powerful datetime arithmetic, value checking and waste storage space.

To have the values truncated to minute precision, use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that uses `date_trunc` on the value.

If you want to ascertain that only such values are stored, add a check constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend not to drop seconds or anything from the stored data. Because it will create issues while you process the data later. And if you have to eliminate anything, you may eliminate it while retrieving the data.

Use the following code while creation of table

```
col_name timestamp without time zone DEFAULT timezone('gmt'::text, now())
```

This will give you a result as shown in the following image:

[image]

Good Luck.